# Computing large distance matrix with pgrouting?

Tags: postgis, pgrouting

The last weeks I have tried to make a Distance Matrix with pgrouting.

On small numbers I get a result. For instance < 100 will be 1 sec. < 1000 aprox 15 min. and 2000 aprox 20 min.  If I am trying to go for larger  numbers, for instance 4000, my computer crashes.... I have tried to change shared buffers, temp buffers, but that seems to make the system more unstable.

I am using postgreSQL 9.6, pgrouting 2.4.1   on a WIN 7 machine with 8GB RAM.
On Pgadmin query tool.

```
SELECT start_vid, end_vid, agg_cost FROM pgr_dijkstraCostMatrix(
    'SELECT gid AS id, source, target, trunc(length_m) AS cost, trunc(length_m) AS reverse_cost FROM public.ways',
    (SELECT array_agg(id) FROM  public.ways_vertices_pgr WHERE id < 100)
);
```

Does any one have some advice?

I would like a matrix to try before I would go for a compromise like Euclidean.

Comment: Did you ever arrive at a solution to this problem? I'm having the same issue using pgrouting 2.6.0.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried doing it by small pieces and saving the results on a table for every query?
Using LIMIT and OFFSET in the "public.ways_vertices_pgr" array may help.

I think it's a problem related to your hardware capabilities.